How to reduce the number of copies needed to merge two lists?
I have some paragraphs:

A love that is generous and outgoing, that acts and takes risks, may at times make mistakes. Here we may find timely the witness of Maria Gabriella Perin, who lost her father shortly after her birth: she reflects on how this influenced her life, in a relationship that did not last but that left her a mother and now a grandmother. “What I know is that God makes stories. In his genius and mercy, he takes our triumphs and our failures and weaves beautiful tapestries that are full of irony. The reverse of the fabric may look messy with its tangled threads – the events of our life – and maybe this is the side we dwell on when we doubt. But the right side of the tapestry displays a magnificent story, and this is the side that God sees”.[109] When older people look at life closely, often they instinctively know what lies behind the tangled threads, and they recognize what God can create even out of our mistakes.

If we journey together, young and old, we can be firmly rooted in the present, and from here, revisit the past and look to the future. To revisit the past in order to learn from history and heal old wounds that at times still trouble us. To look to the future in order to nourish our enthusiasm, cause dreams to emerge, awaken prophecies and enable hope to blossom. Together, we can learn from one another, warm hearts, inspire minds with the light of the Gospel, and lend new strength to our hands.

Roots are not anchors chaining us to past times and preventing us from facing the present and creating something new. Instead, they are a fixed point from which we can grow and meet new challenges. It does us no good “to sit down and long for times past; we must meet our culture with realism and love and fill it with the Gospel. We are sent today to proclaim the Good News of Jesus to a new age. We need to love this time with all its opportunities and risks, its joys and sorrows, its riches and its limits, its successes and failures”.[110]

During the Synod, one of the young auditors from the Samoan Islands spoke of the Church as a canoe, in which the elderly help to keep on course by judging the position of the stars, while the young keep rowing, imagining what waits for them ahead. Let us steer clear of young people who think that adults represent a meaningless past, and those adults who always think they know how young people should act. Instead, let us all climb aboard the same canoe and together seek a better world, with the constantly renewed momentum of the Holy Spirit.


and

L’amour qui se donne et qui opère se trompe souvent. Celui qui agit, celui qui risque, peut commettre des erreurs. Il peut être à présent intéressant de rapporter ici le témoignage de Maria Gabriela Perin: orpheline de père depuis sa naissance, elle réfléchit sur la manière dont une relation, qui n’a pas duré mais qui l’a rendue mère et maintenant grand-mère, a influencé sa vie : « Ce que je sais c’est que Dieu crée des histoires. Dans son génie et sa miséricorde, il prend nos victoires et nos échecs et tisse de belles tapisseries pleines d’humour. Le revers du tissage peut sembler désordonné avec ses fils emmêlés – les événements de notre vie – sûrement c’est sur ce côté que nous faisons une fixation quand nous avons des doutes. Cependant, le bon côté de la tapisserie présente une histoire magnifique, et c’est le côté que Dieu voit ».[109] Quand les personnes aînées regardent attentivement la vie, elles savent souvent de manière instinctive ce qu’il y a derrière les fils emmêlés, et elles reconnaissent ce que Dieu fait de façon créative, même avec nos erreurs.

Si nous marchons ensemble, jeunes et vieux, nous pourrons être bien enracinés dans le présent, et, de là, fréquenter le passé et l’avenir : fréquenter le passé, pour apprendre de l’histoire et pour guérir les blessures qui parfois nous conditionnent ; fréquenter l’avenir pour nourrir l’enthousiasme, faire germer des rêves, susciter des prophéties, faire fleurir des espérances. De cette manière, nous pourrons, unis, apprendre les uns des autres, réchauffer les cœurs, éclairer nos esprits de la lumière de l’Evangile et donner de nouvelles forces à nos mains.

Les racines ne sont pas des ancres qui nous enchaînent à d’autres époques et qui nous empêchent de nous incarner dans le monde actuel pour faire naître quelque chose de nouveau. Elles sont, au contraire, un point d’ancrage qui nous permet de nous développer et de répondre à de nouveaux défis. Il ne faut pas non plus « nous asseoir pour regretter le temps passé ; nous devons accepter avec réalisme et amour notre culture et la remplir de l’Evangile. Nous sommes envoyés aujourd’hui pour annoncer la Bonne Nouvelle de Jésus aux temps nouveaux. Nous devons aimer notre temps avec ses possibilités et ses risques, avec ses joies et ses souffrances, avec ses risques et ses limites, avec ses succès et ses erreurs ».[110]

Au Synode, l’un des jeunes auditeurs, venant des îles Samoa, a dit que l’Eglise est une pirogue, sur laquelle les vieux aident à maintenir la direction en interprétant la position des étoiles, et les jeunes rament avec force en imaginant ce qui les attend plus loin. Ne nous laissons entraîner ni par les jeunes qui pensent que les adultes sont un passé qui ne compte plus, déjà caduque, ni par les adultes qui croient savoir toujours comment doivent se comporter les jeunes. Il est mieux que nous montions tous dans la même pirogue et que nous cherchions ensemble un monde meilleur, sous l’impulsion toujours nouvelle de l’Esprit Saint.


at here and here
I am joining two documents in the form by using paracol package in LaTeX


I tried with some paragraphs like this
list1 = {"198. A love that is generous and outgoing, that acts and \
takes risks, may at times make mistakes. Here we may find timely the \
witness of Maria Gabriella Perin, who lost her father shortly after \
her birth: she reflects on how this influenced her life, in a \
relationship that did not last but that left her a mother and now a \
grandmother. \[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote]What I know is that God makes \
stories. In his genius and mercy, he takes our triumphs and our \
failures and weaves beautiful tapestries that are full of irony. The \
reverse of the fabric may look messy with its tangled threads \[Dash] \
the events of our life \[Dash] and maybe this is the side we dwell on \
when we doubt. But the right side of the tapestry displays a \
magnificent story, and this is the side that God sees\
\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote].[109] When older people look at life \
closely, often they instinctively know what lies behind the tangled \
threads, and they recognize what God can create even out of our \
mistakes.\\switchcolumn", 
   "199. If we journey together, young and old, we can be firmly \
rooted in the present, and from here, revisit the past and look to \
the future. To revisit the past in order to learn from history and \
heal old wounds that at times still trouble us. To look to the future \
in order to nourish our enthusiasm, cause dreams to emerge, awaken \
prophecies and enable hope to blossom. Together, we can learn from \
one another, warm hearts, inspire minds with the light of the Gospel, \
and lend new strength to our hands.\\switchcolumn", 
   "200. Roots are not anchors chaining us to past times and \
preventing us from facing the present and creating something new. \
Instead, they are a fixed point from which we can grow and meet new \
challenges. It does us no good \[OpenCurlyDoubleQuote]to sit down and \
long for times past; we must meet our culture with realism and love \
and fill it with the Gospel. We are sent today to proclaim the Good \
News of Jesus to a new age. We need to love this time with all its \
opportunities and risks, its joys and sorrows, its riches and its \
limits, its successes and \
failures\[CloseCurlyDoubleQuote].[110]\\switchcolumn", 
   "201. During the Synod,one of the young auditors from the Samoan \
Islands spoke of the Church as a canoe,in which the elderly help to \
keep on course by judging the position of the stars,while the young \
keep rowing,imagining what waits for them ahead.Let us steer clear of \
young people who think that adults represent a meaningless past,and \
those adults who always think they know how young people should \
act.Instead,let us all climb aboard the same canoe and together seek \
a better world,with the constantly renewed momentum of the Holy \
Spirit.\\switchcolumn"};
list2 = {"198. L\[CloseCurlyQuote]amour qui se donne et qui opère se \
trompe souvent. Celui qui agit, celui qui risque, peut commettre des \
erreurs. Il peut être à présent intéressant de rapporter ici le \
témoignage de Maria Gabriela Perin: orpheline de père depuis sa \
naissance, elle réfléchit sur la manière dont une relation, qui n\
\[CloseCurlyQuote]a pas duré mais qui l\[CloseCurlyQuote]a rendue \
mère et maintenant grand-mère, a influencé sa vie : « Ce que je sais \
c\[CloseCurlyQuote]est que Dieu crée des histoires. Dans son génie et \
sa miséricorde, il prend nos victoires et nos échecs et tisse de \
belles tapisseries pleines d\[CloseCurlyQuote]humour. Le revers du \
tissage peut sembler désordonné avec ses fils emmêlés \[Dash] les \
événements de notre vie \[Dash] sûrement c\[CloseCurlyQuote]est sur \
ce côté que nous faisons une fixation quand nous avons des doutes. \
Cependant, le bon côté de la tapisserie présente une histoire \
magnifique, et c\[CloseCurlyQuote]est le côté que Dieu voit ».[109] \
Quand les personnes aînées regardent attentivement la vie, elles \
savent souvent de manière instinctive ce qu\[CloseCurlyQuote]il y a \
derrière les fils emmêlés, et elles reconnaissent ce que Dieu fait de \
façon créative, même avec nos erreurs.
\\switchcolumn*",
   "199. Si nous marchons ensemble, jeunes et vieux, nous pourrons \
être bien enracinés dans le présent, et, de là, fréquenter le passé \
et l\[CloseCurlyQuote]avenir : fréquenter le passé, pour apprendre de \
l\[CloseCurlyQuote]histoire et pour guérir les blessures qui parfois \
nous conditionnent ; fréquenter l\[CloseCurlyQuote]avenir pour \
nourrir l\[CloseCurlyQuote]enthousiasme, faire germer des rêves, \
susciter des prophéties, faire fleurir des espérances. De cette \
manière, nous pourrons, unis, apprendre les uns des autres, \
réchauffer les cœurs, éclairer nos esprits de la lumière de l\
\[CloseCurlyQuote]Evangile et donner de nouvelles forces à nos mains.\
\\switchcolumn*", 
   "200. Les racines ne sont pas des ancres qui nous enchaînent à d\
\[CloseCurlyQuote]autres époques et qui nous empêchent de nous \
incarner dans le monde actuel pour faire naître quelque chose de \
nouveau. Elles sont, au contraire, un point \
d\[CloseCurlyQuote]ancrage qui nous permet de nous développer et de \
répondre à de nouveaux défis. Il ne faut pas non plus « nous asseoir \
pour regretter le temps passé ; nous devons accepter avec réalisme et \
amour notre culture et la remplir de l\[CloseCurlyQuote]Evangile. \
Nous sommes envoyés aujourd\[CloseCurlyQuote]hui pour annoncer la \
Bonne Nouvelle de Jésus aux temps nouveaux. Nous devons aimer notre \
temps avec ses possibilités et ses risques, avec ses joies et ses \
souffrances, avec ses risques et ses limites, avec ses succès et ses \
erreurs ».[110]
\\switchcolumn*", 
   "201. Au Synode, l\[CloseCurlyQuote]un des jeunes auditeurs, \
venant des îles Samoa, a dit que l\[CloseCurlyQuote]Eglise est une \
pirogue, sur laquelle les vieux aident à maintenir la direction en \
interprétant la position des étoiles, et les jeunes rament avec force \
en imaginant ce qui les attend plus loin. Ne nous laissons entraîner \
ni par les jeunes qui pensent que les adultes sont un passé qui ne \
compte plus, déjà caduque, ni par les adultes qui croient savoir \
toujours comment doivent se comporter les jeunes. Il est mieux que \
nous montions tous dans la même pirogue et que nous cherchions \
ensemble un monde meilleur, sous l\[CloseCurlyQuote]impulsion \
toujours nouvelle de l\[CloseCurlyQuote]Esprit Saint.
\\switchcolumn*"};
mixedList = Riffle[list1, list2];
latexItems = StringJoin["\\item " <> # <> "\n" & /@ mixedList];
latexOutput = "\\begin{itemize}\n" <> latexItems <> "\\end{itemize}"
Export["output.tex", latexOutput, "Text"];

I copied paraphs by my hand. How can I reduce number of copies to join two lists to put the paragraphs into list1 and list2 by using paragraphs from two above links directly?

I think you're asking about fetching the paragraphs automatically, not  about how to process the paragraphs once you have them. If that's incorrect, then please be more specific about the problem you're having processing the paragraphs. As for fetching them:
textEN = 
  URLRead[
    "https://www.vatican.va/content/francesco/en/apost_exhortations/documents/papa-francesco_esortazione-ap_20190325_christus-vivit.html", 
    "Body"];
textENString = ImportString[textEN, "HTML"];
paragraphsEN = StringCases[textENString, RegularExpression["(?m)^\\d+ *\\..+$"]];

textFR = 
  URLRead[
    "https://www.vatican.va/content/francesco/fr/apost_exhortations/documents/papa-francesco_esortazione-ap_20190325_christus-vivit.html",
    "Body"];
textFRString = ImportString[textFR, "HTML"];
paragraphsFR = StringCases[textFRString, RegularExpression["(?m)^\\d+ *\\..+$"]];

The duplication computations could be removed. You could parameterize the "en" and "fr" and turn the processing into strings and paragraphs into a function for reuse.

I get this situation paragraph in paragraph `https://www.vatican.va/content/benedict-xvi/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_ben-xvi_enc_20051225_deus-caritas-est.html'  How can I solve this problem?
